# How to use memcache in a namespaced application?

Tags: php, namespaces

I want to use memcache into my application. I have enabled php_memcache.dll in php.ini file and normal **memcache is working fine in simple PHP**.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
$test = $memcache->get("A");
if(empty($test)){
       echo "setting cache";
       $memcache->set("A","Cache contents",MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED,50);
}
echo $test;
```

But I don't know how to create object for Memcache in **Zend Framework 2** for normal Memcache, when I am trying to shows error as:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\Memcache' not found
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to initialize `Memcache` object from your controller, which is in `Application\Controller` namespace. In this case, it looks for `Memcache` in the same namespace. You need to refer it from global namespace as:

```
$memcache = new \Memcache;
```